# Automatic compilation when file changes

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to do a automatic compilation with typescript? Like when using mindscape for CoffeScript? You just save the file and the extension compiles your codes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is supported in VS2012 RTM using the latest [WebEssentials 2012 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) (released yesterday with a neat TypeScript double windows editor)

EDIT :

**WebEssential2012 Version 3.0 has been stripped of any TypeScript features** since it conflicts with the latest improvements of the official TypeScript Visual Studio plugin.

Compile on save is now **natively supported by the plugin since TypeScript v0.8.2** and if you edit the project file : https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported in Visual Studio currently. There is an issue already open on CodePlex to track this issue; you can add your vote there.

http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/12

Comment: Is it only supported for visual studio pro?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the links displayed here: http://vswebessentials.com/changelog
http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save

a warning though: support for TypeScript was removed from Web Essentials

I don't know currently how to compile on save for website projects...