# Refreshing .js files when the TypeScript file is saved

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic compilation when file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719582/automatic-compilation-when-file-changes)

When I add a TypeScript file to my project in Visual Studio, a JavaScript file (the TypeScript compilation result) appears underneath the .ts file in the Solution Explorer.

The .js file is refreshed when I build the project. Is there a way to get this file to refresh when the .ts file is saved without having to rebuild? (as is the case with T4 files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially the answer is, not yet. 
However you have some work-arounds available:

[How to watch and compile all TypeScript sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799237/how-to-watch-and-compile-all-typescript-sources)